# Angularj same example works on online demo but fails in fiddle. What gives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

This code example does not work here in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/viralpatel/aLDJJ/ but works on the demo by same author:http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-controller-tutorial/.
Since it also fails on my fiddles, I'd appreciate any insights as to what is going on.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<title>Hello World, AngularJS - ViralPatel.net</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="ContactController">
     Email:<input type="text" ng-model="newcontact"/>
    <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
    <h2>Contacts</h2>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts"> {{ contact }} </li>
    </ul>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ContactController($scope) {
        $scope.contacts = ["hi@email.com", "hello@email.com"];

        $scope.add = function() {
        $scope.contacts.push($scope.newcontact);
        $scope.newcontact = "";
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ng-model` of your `input` is `contact`, in the function it is looking for `$scope.newcontact`. Change this, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/aLDJJ/157/

```
function ContactController($scope) {
    $scope.contacts = ["viralpatel.net@gmail.com", "hello@email.com"];

    $scope.add = function() {
        $scope.contacts.push($scope.contact); //Changed here
        $scope.contact = ""; //Changed here
    }
}

<input type="text" ng-model="contact" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle has a different variable `contact`  bound to the scope.  The variable you are puhing into the contacts array is `newcontact` which is not defined in the scope.  I changed all of the references to this variable and called it `newContact` for clarity.

This fiddle will work: http://jsfiddle.net/GruyereEmmentaler/aLDJJ/158/

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="ContactController">

        Email:<input type="text" ng-model="newContact" />

        <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>

        <h2>Contacts</h2>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts"> {{ contact }} </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

And the javascript:

```
function ContactController($scope) {
    $scope.contacts = ["viralpatel.net@gmail.com", "hello@email.com"];

    $scope.add = function() {
        $scope.contacts.push($scope.newContact);
        $scope.newContact = "";
    }
}
```